# Method mocked assigns value to a variable

Tags: unit-testing, python-2.7, testing, mocking, pytest

New to Mock here. So I have a script like:

```
def method_being_tested():
    self.foo = OtherClass()
    self.foo.method_trouble()
    if "Hub" in self.foo.names:
        execute some instructions here
```

Now the problem is that in my test suite I have patched the method_trouble of OtherClass. Now the variable "names" is assigned a meaningful value when method_troubled is called. Since I am not really calling the method_trouble, but patching it so the instructions inside the if are never executed. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: You can patch `.names` as well.